# How do I map an action to a held key?

Tags: shortcut-keys, compiz

Thanks to CompizConfig, I can map pretty much action I want to a keyboard shortcut.

But I can't choose a shortcut that implies holding a key for a certain time.

I think there must be a way to do it, because the 'Keyboard shortcuts' window appears when holding 'Super' for some time. But I didn't find it in compiz.

How can I map an action to 'hold key X' ?